# Saving Particular Node in XML File

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xmlnode, selectsinglenode

I am populating textboxes with information from a particular node based on it's `ConfirmNum`.  Then when all info is updated, I am saving information (by a submit button) back to the particular node.

However, upon saving, every node in the XML file that **was empty** drops down to another line.

**Example XML Before Save:**

```
<OnlineBanking>
  <Transactions>
    <Txn>
      <Login></Login>
      <UserName>userName</UserName>
      <CustomerName>CustomerName</CustomerName>
      <ConfirmNum>1234</ConfirmNum>
    </Txn>
  </Transactions>
</OnlineBanking>
```

My code (below) will save the information for that node, based on the `Page.aspx?CID=1234` number. However, every node in the entire XML file that was blank, will now have a line break in it.  Not just the `Txn` we just edited, but all.

**Here is my code:**

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XmlDocument item = new XmlDocument();
    item.Load(xmlFileName);
    if (CID != "")
    {
        XmlNode xlist = item.SelectSingleNode("OnlineBanking/Transactions/Txn[ConfirmNum=" + CID + "]");
        if (xlist != null)
        {
            xlist.ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerText = tbLogin.Text;
            xlist.ChildNodes.Item(1).InnerText = tbUserName.Text;
            xlist.ChildNodes.Item(2).InnerText = tbCustomerName.Text;
            item.Save(xmlFileName);
        }
    }
}
```

**Example XML After Save:**

```
<OnlineBanking>
  <Transactions>
    <Txn>
      <Login>
      </Login>
      <UserName>userName</UserName>
      <CustomerName>CustomerName</CustomerName>
      <ConfirmNum>1234</ConfirmNum>
    </Txn>
  </Transactions>
</OnlineBanking>
```

Note how the `<login>` is on another line than `</login>`.  This is what I am talking about. Hope someone can see clearly what I am not doing.

Comment: What does it matter one line or two?  Is it messing with a program or your human sense of perfection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the PreserveWhitespace property to True and see if it will stop inserting line breaks upon calling Save:

```
XmlDocument item = new XmlDocument();
item.PreserveWhitespace = true;
item.Load(xmlFileName);
```

Comment: When I save and run the code I get an error: `System.ArgumentException: The string for white space contains an invalid character.`  For this line: `xlist.ChildNodes.Item(2).InnerText = tbCustomerName.Text;`

Comment: I put `item.PreserveWhitespace = true;` right before `item.Save(xmlFileName);` and it put everything on one line.

Comment: What is the string you are trying to assign to CustomerName?

Comment: The `tbCustomerName` had a value in it: First Last

Comment: @bemused, I haven't figured it out yet.   I meant the entire XML file was on one line, not just the <login></login>

Answer (score 0):

One compromise is:

```
if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tbLogin.Text))
   xlist.ChildNodes.Item(0).IsEmpty = true;
else
   xlist.ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerText = tbLogin.Text;
```

This will give you:

```
<Login />
```

Comment: The program that reads the `<login></login>` line will not recognize it as `<login />`.